# Android Debug Search

Tags: android, debugging, search, android-activity

I am trying to debug an activity that uses the android os main search to search my SQLite database.  Is this possible in eclipse?  It doesn't appear to be hitting the breakpoint in the onCreate of my search activity.

I think it is because my content provider is not starting when I hit search.  I see other content providers starting like this one:

```
04-26 18:48:28.178: INFO/ActivityThread(463): Publishing provider user_dictionary: com.android.providers.userdictionary.UserDictionaryProvider
```

I am assuming this means I am missing something in my app but I have yet to figure out what it is.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes you can debug Android Activity's using eclipse :-)

Post your Logcat if you want help with the issue.

Answer (score 0):

Remember to add android:debuggable="true" to the application element in AndroidManifest.xml